# ¿Como crear un comparativo de valores calculados con php desde un result-set?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo la siguiente el siguiente result-set traído de la consulta que se describe en el código a continuación. Lo que hace el código php es recorrer el result-set filtrando por **dos variables bandera: origen y destino**. A continución durante la iteración por cada origen y destino encontrado compara los registros en los campos: **importe y formato_salto** en caso de ser mayor a 1 y el segundo campo vacío. El registro es contabilizado como boleto vendido, si caso contrario si es menor de 0 o con número negativo es contado como cancelado. Si ya no encuentra más registros con el mismo origen y destino: hace la resta vendido - cancelado  = neto. Tanto en importe como boletos. E imprime esos valores calculados correspondiente a cada origen y destino. Antes de cerrar el bucle while las banderas toman el siguiente valor encontrado de: origen y destino.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT Area_de_Venta, Clave_Area, FContable, Importe, Formato_Salto, Tipo, Corrida, Origen, Destino FROM db_ventas.tb_vtas WHERE Empresa_Corrida <> '' and FContable between '$fecha_in_A' and '$fecha_fn_A' and Area_de_Venta = '$a_venta' order by Area_de_Venta, Origen, Destino, Importe, FContable

 while ( $rowA = $sqlA->fetch_assoc() ) {   //bucle para recorrer array asociativo de A

           //COMPARANDO BANDERAS DE A
       if ( ($flag_origenA == $rowA['Origen']) && ($flag_destinoA == $rowA['Destino']) ) {

          if ( ($rowA['Importe'] > 1) && ($rowA['Formato_Salto'] == '') ) {   //SI SON BOLETOS VENDIDOS

                 $importe_fila = $rowA['Importe']; //extrayendo el importe de cada fila
                 $suma = $suma + $importe_fila;
                 //$rsuma = floor($suma * 10) /10; //redondeo
                 $contador_vendido++; 

              } elseif ( ($rowA['Importe'] <= 0 ) && ($rowA['Formato_Salto'] == '') ) {   //SI SON CANCELADOS

                    $importe_cancel = $rowA['Importe'];
                    $importe_positivo = $importe_cancel * -1; //conversión a positivo 
                    $suma_cancel = $suma_cancel + $importe_positivo;
                    //$rsuma_cancel = floor($suma_cancel * 10)/10;
                    $contador_cancel++;
                }
                    $contador_neto = $contador_vendido - $contador_cancel;
                    $imp_neto = $suma - $suma_cancel;
                    $a_venta = $rowA['Area_de_Venta'];
                    $origen = $rowA['Origen'];
                    $destino = $rowA['Destino'];
        // }  // cierre del if de: año y mes 
      } else {   //else de BANDERAS: ORIGEN Y DESTINO

               <tr>
                 <td><?php echo $a_venta; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $contador_neto; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $imp_neto; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $origen; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $destino; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $contador_neto; ?></td>
               </tr>

         // reinician contadores
         $contador_vendido = 0; 
         $suma = 0;
         $rsuma = 0;

         $contador_cancel = 0;
         $suma_cancel = 0;
         $rsuma_cancel = 0;

         $contador_neto = 0;
         $imp_neto = 0;


           if ( ($rowA['Importe'] > 1) && ($rowA['Formato_Salto'] == '') ) {   //SI SON BOLETOS VENDIDOS

               $importe_fila = $rowA['Importe']; //extrayendo el importe de cada fila correspondiente a un area_venta
               $suma = $suma + $importe_fila;
               //$rsuma = floor($suma * 10) /10; //redondeo
               $contador_vendido++; 

              } elseif ( ($rowA['Importe'] <= 0 ) && ($rowA['Formato_Salto'] == '') ) {
                  $importe_cancel = $rowA['Importe'];
                  $importe_positivo = $importe_cancel * -1; //conversión a positivo 
                  $suma_cancel = $suma_cancel + $importe_positivo;
                  //$suma_cancel = floor($suma_cancel * 10)/10;
                  $contador_cancel++;
              }
                  $contador_neto = $contador_vendido - $contador_cancel;
                  $imp_neto = $suma - $suma_cancel;
                  $a_venta = $rowA['Area_de_Venta'];
                  $origen = $rowA['Origen'];
                  $destino = $rowA['Destino'];
          } // SI NO ES EL PRIMER REGISTRO

                //FLAGS TOMAN EL VALOR DE LA SIGUENTE FILA, RECORRIDA EN EL BUCLE
               $flag_origenA = $rowA['Origen']; 
               $flag_destinoA = $rowA['Destino']; 

      } //while A

         <tr>
           <td><?php echo $a_venta; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $contador_neto; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $imp_neto; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $origen; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $destino; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $contador_neto; ?></td>
         </tr>
```

Como salida, obtengo la siguiente impresión en tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto sale bien dando como entrada un área_venta, y dos fechas (inicial y final). Ahora bien lo que no puedo hacer es dar otro par de fechas (inicial y final). Calcular lo mismo que en el anterior proceso e imprimir un comparativo de importe_neto y boletos_netos entre: rango_de_fechas_A y rango_de_fechas_B: Y tener como salida algo así: imprimiendo 0 en las columnas donde no haya registros de importe y boletos.
Estaba intentando con otro bucle while anidado, pero no pude hacer la relación.
¿Es posible meter otro bucle y en medio hacer la comparación para imprimir las diferencias correspondientes? O habría otra mejor manera de hacerlo.

Y tener como salida algo así en la tabla, (con azul los resultados de un rango de Fechas A y con verde los resultados de un rango de Fechas B ):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Armando, solucionaste tu problema?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías modificar tu consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
$sql="SELECT Area_de_Venta, Clave_Area, FContable, Importe, Formato_Salto, Tipo, Corrida, Origen, Destino, 'RangoA' AS Rango   
    FROM db_ventas.tb_vtas 
    WHERE Empresa_Corrida <>'' and FContable between  '$fecha_in_A' and '$fecha_fn_A' 
    and Area_de_Venta = '$a_venta' order by Area_de_Venta, Origen, Destino, Importe, FContable
UNION 
SELECT Area_de_Venta, Clave_Area, FContable, Importe, Formato_Salto, Tipo, Corrida, Origen, Destino, 'RangoB' as Rango 
    FROM db_ventas.tb_vtas 
    WHERE Empresa_Corrida <>'' and FContable between  '$fecha_in_B' and '$fecha_fn_B' 
    and Area_de_Venta = '$a_venta' order by Area_de_Venta, Origen, Destino, Importe, FContable";
```

Tendras en un solo resultado registros de los dos rangos de fechas y diferenciarlo en la iteracion por el campo "Rango", que contendra los valores "RangoA", "RangoB" según sea el caso.

Comment: corriendo el script en mysql, me esta marcando error de sintaxis al usar las sentencias union y order by.